# PC only boots from Linux-based media and won't boot from DOS-based media

Tags: linux, bios, troubleshooting, bootable-media, disk-operating-system

I have this problem where the PC only seems to boot from a floppy disk or CD if it was created as a Linux-based bootable media. If it was created as a DOS-based bootable media the system just freezes at the starting point of the boot process. I originally asked this under question [139515](https://superuser.com/questions/139515/working-bootable-cd-now-suddenly-freezes-at-starting-point) for CD booting only, and based on the given answers, I was under the impression the problem was with the CD-ROM drive; however, I have since installed a newly purchased CD-ROM drive and the same freezing occurs. This then made me try the DOS bootable floppy disk approach and I was quite surprised that it exhibited the same freezing problem. I then tried try a Linux bootable floppy and everything booted from it without any issues.

As I mentioned in my original question, the PC was booting just fine from the DOS-based bootable CD, and then it suddenly decides to pull this freezing stunt. I can't remember if I changed anything in the BIOS settings that may I have caused the problem, but I am wondering if that could be the case - it is currently using the *Award Module BIOS v4.60PGMA*. Can anyone help?

Comment: If you think it might be a BIOS settings problem then you should attempt to reset the BIOS settings to defaults and see if that works.

Comment: I recall doing that and it still was not working. This happened a long time ago and the problem seemed temporary. The PC worked again after this short period of odd behaviour. Never figured out what the issue was.